# File.Replace not behaving as expected

Tags: vb.net, file-io

The following code should replace the executable and restart the application, which should work because the content should be replaced but not in the current running instance:

```
Dim tmppath As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName

Private Sub YesBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles YesBtn.Click
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadFileCompleted
    client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://github.com/Yttrium-tYcLief/Scrotter/raw/master/latest/scrotter.exe"), tmppath)
End Sub

Public Sub client_DownloadFileCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    File.Replace(tmppath, Application.ExecutablePath, Nothing)
    Application.Restart()
End Sub
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d9h163f.aspx),

> Pass **Nothing** to the destinationBackupFileName parameter if you do not want to create a backup of the file being replaced.

However, what *really* happens is that it *does* create a backup (if the .exe is `scrotter.exe`, then the new backup is `scrotter.exe~RF729c1fe9.TMP`). Additionally, a new empty folder called "False" is created in the root directory.

All I want is to replace the running executable with my file and not have any backups or extra folders. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if this happens only with the executable running? I have tested with a simple text file and what you describe doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty hard to explain this with the posted code, this smells like a some kind of 3rd party utility stepping in and avoiding the problem your code has.  It will never work when you pass Nothing for the backup file name.  It is **required** if you want to replace an executable file that's also loaded into memory.  The CLR creates a memory mapped file object for the assembly so Windows can page-in the data from the assembly into RAM on demand.  With the big advantage that this doesn't take any space in the paging file.  That MMF also puts a hard lock on the file so nobody can alter the file content.  That would be disastrous.

That's a lock on the file data, not the directory entry for the file.  So renaming the file still works.  Which is what File.Replace() does when you provide a non-null backup file name, it renames the assembly so you can still create a file with the same name and not get in trouble with the lock.  You can delete the backup copy afterwards, assuming that your program still has sufficient rights to actually remove the file when it starts back up.  That's unusual with UAC these days.  Or just not bother, disk space is cheap and having a backup copy around to deal with accidents is something you can call a feature.

So get ahead and use File.Replace() properly, use the 3rd argument. Don't forget to delete that backup file before you call Replace().

Comment: I'm going to end up just creating the backup in %temp% with a non-random filename, and check for that file every time my app starts - if it's there, it'll be deleted.

Comment: Be careful with that.  It is essential that the backup file is on the same drive so it can be simply moved instead of copied.  %temp% doesn't provide that guarantee.  Boilerplate is the exact same directory with, say, a .bak filename extension added.  Also makes it much easier to find the backup file back when you want to delete or restore it, another thing that %temp% cannot guarantee since it can change.

Comment: So would it be better to create a .bak file in the directory my executable is in, and then check for it and remove it when launching? I'm concerned the user might interfere with it or have another file there. Could I generate a temp file name using System.IO.Path.GetRandomFilename and then save that filename to the registry or something? It would be safer than just assuming the .bak file in the directory is the backup of my application (this application is portable, it doesn't install to a directory, though I should consider doing that)

Answer (score 0):

I think the .exe is locked so long as your process runs - which instance runs is of no concern.
To avoid this, I would place the updater in a separate .exe and shut down your main apllication while updating.